# Why VecDeque is_empty is blocking further borrows?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a following function which works correctly. I wanted to optimize it a bit and convert two similar code blocks into a closure or a function. After a few attempts I still see some borrow checker errors. It looks like the VecDeque `is_empty` blocks further code. I do not want to change queue and visited data structures only to satisfy the borrow checker. It is possible to do that?

```
use std::collections::{VecDeque, HashSet, HashMap};

fn day_7() -> i32 {
    let lines: Vec<String> = r"light red bags contain 1 bright white bag, 2 muted yellow bags.
dark orange bags contain 3 bright white bags, 4 muted yellow bags.
bright white bags contain 1 shiny gold bag.
muted yellow bags contain 2 shiny gold bags, 9 faded blue bags.
shiny gold bags contain 1 dark olive bag, 2 vibrant plum bags.
dark olive bags contain 3 faded blue bags, 4 dotted black bags.
vibrant plum bags contain 5 faded blue bags, 6 dotted black bags.
faded blue bags contain no other bags.
dotted black bags contain no other bags.".split('\n').map(|s| s.to_owned()).collect();
    let root_name = String::from("shiny gold");

    let mut connections: HashMap<String, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();

    for line in &lines {
        let arr: Vec<&str> = line.split(" bags contain ").collect();
        let parent = arr[0];
        let values: Vec<&str> = arr[1].split(", ").collect();
        for val in values {
            if val.starts_with("no other bags") { continue; }
            let parts: Vec<&str> = val.split_whitespace().collect();
            let child = format!("{} {}", parts[1], parts[2]);
            let child_list = connections.entry(child).or_insert(vec![]);
            if !child_list.iter().any(|s| s == parent) {
                child_list.push(parent.to_owned());
            }
        }
    }

    let mut queue: VecDeque<&str> = VecDeque::new();
    let mut visited: HashSet<&str> = HashSet::new();

    // a closure or a function should start here
    visited.insert(&root_name);
    if let Some(list) = connections.get(&root_name) {
        for n in list { queue.push_back(n); }
    }
    // convert above 4 lines to a closure or a function

    // let visit = |name| {
    //     visited.insert(name);
    //     if let Some(list) = connections.get(name) {
    //         for n in list { queue.push_back(n); }
    //     }
    // }
    // visit(&root_name);
    
    let mut result = 0;
    while !queue.is_empty() {
        match queue.pop_front() {
            None => break,
            Some(cur) => {
                if visited.contains(cur) { continue; };
                result += 1;

                // the second use of the code block
                visited.insert(cur);
                if let Some(list) = connections.get(cur) {
                    for n in list { queue.push_back(n); }
                }
                // visit(cur);
            }
        }
    }

    result
}

fn main() {
    println!("day 7: {}", day_7());
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&edition=2018&gist=71fcb655bc8c4c95d3231074ff93e82f)

Update: This the correct function from the correct answer. Notice that `visited` and `queue` don't have explicit lifetime parameters.

```
    fn visit<'a>(name: &'a str, visited: &mut HashSet<&'a str>, queue: &mut VecDeque<&'a str>, connections: &'a HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) {
        visited.insert(name);
        if let Some(list) = connections.get(name) {
            for n in list { queue.push_back(n); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code you shared compiles and runs. Can you share a minimal reproducible example of your problem?

Comment: Or share the code that doesn't work but you want it to work

Comment: @YannickFunk You are right, I just added a closure I was working on. Just uncomment it and you see the problem.

Comment: Yes, the code works but I want to do that small refactoring to learn Rust better. And the task is harder than I expected. Adding a such closure to already working code should be easy.

Comment: It's great that you have the solution to your question! You should post it as an answer rather than an edit to your question and then potentially accept that answer. That way, the question shows up as solved in search results, people can vote on your answer, and your solution can be more helpful to future people with the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, factoring code out into lambdas is somewhat incompatible with the borrow checker. The reason is that the lambda is essentially a struct that contains references to all the variables it closes over. Thus, if the lambda needs to refer to a variable, it will have to be frozen for the entire time the lambda exists, and if it needs to mutate it, it will have to be the only thing that does so.

This is an unfortunate interaction of the borrow rules. I am not aware of any RFC that would help with this, but a future language extension that would make code like this work is not out of the question.

As for workarounds, you can define a function-local macro. Macros can also close over local variables, so this works out quite nicely:

```
    macro_rules! visit {
        ($name:expr) => {
            let name = $name;
            visited.insert(name);
            if let Some(list) = connections.get(name) {
                for n in list { queue.push_back(n); }
            }
        }
    }
    
    visit!(&root_name);
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a99f0cbe122e74c31758550bf30564c8)

Note how I immediately bind the macro parameter to a variable. This is to avoid a footgun: [when you repeat a macro parameter name, the expression passed in as argument is evaluated twice](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0bc41dc958fd5c4523cf07ca761a1ec9). This is desirable for some macros, but when you want to use them like lambdas — not so much.

If you'd rather avoid using macros for this purpose, you can also consider making the required variables explicit arguments of your function. A good way to make sure you've got all of them is to use an internal `fn` function, as those can't capture variables:

```
    fn visit<'a>(name: &'a str, visited: &mut HashSet<&'a str>, queue: &mut VecDeque<&'a str>, connections: &'a HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) {
        visited.insert(name);
        if let Some(list) = connections.get(name) {
            for n in list { queue.push_back(n); }
        }
    }

    visit(root_name.as_str(), &mut visited, &mut queue, &connections);
```

In this case you need to be careful about the lifetime annotations: `'a` is the lifetime of all the strings involved, and if you also say `visited: &'a mut`, then `visited` will stay borrowed as long as the strings exist.

By the way: you can write your loop much better with a `while let`:

```
    while let Some(cur) = queue.pop_front() {
        if visited.contains(cur) { continue; };
        result += 1;
        visit!(cur);
    }
```

Comment: Great tips with `while let` and `macro_rules`! Thanks! What about refactoring to a function with visited, queue and connections passed as parameters? I tried this but had to add lifetime parameters which caused other error messages.

Comment: @GregDan Then post the code that didn't work and we'll try to figure out why.

Comment: Here is the version with the function https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&edition=2018&gist=71fcb655bc8c4c95d3231074ff93e82f

Comment: @GregDan You overdid it with the lifetime specification, and said that the mutable references need to have the same lifetime as the strings in your hashmaps. This means that a function with this signature could store something borrowed from `queue` into `visited`. It would be hard to actually do so, as the types are just strings, but imagine that apart from all the elements in the queue, `VecQueue` also owns its own string that describes it in some manner. Here's a version that works: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ccc0af9150b2cc28676f3c2d79db1d09

Comment: That is the solution I was looking for. Two other approaches (macro and RefCell) are also good.

Answer (score 1):

It's not `queue.is_empty()` that is blocking the borrow, it's the closure holding a mutable borrow of `queue` that is blocking all other accesses to `queue`. This includes the call to `queue.is_empty()`, but also `queue.pop_front()`, or anything else you'd want to do with `queue` while the closure that holds it is live.

The standard workaround to this problem is to avoid capturing, and pass `&mut queue` as an explicit argument to the closure. But unfortunately in your case it doesn't work because you would need to also pass `&connections` and `&mut visited` to the closure, and the relationships between their lifetimes are not something the compiler is currently able to infer.

However, there is another way out, although it's not clear whether you'll like it. The core of the issue is that the closure tries to capture a mutable reference to something that you also need to access outside it. Rust does support shared mutable access - through interior mutability. You can wrap `queue` and `connections` in a `RefCell`, like this:

```
let queue: RefCell<VecDeque<&str>> = Default::default();
let visited: RefCell<HashSet<&str>> = Default::default();
```

Now the closure will capture them by *shared reference*, and there will be no problem sharing them with the environment:

```
let visit = |name| {
    visited.borrow_mut().insert(name);
    if let Some(list) = connections.get(name) {
        let mut queue = queue.borrow_mut();
        for n in list {
            queue.push_back(n);
        }
    }
};

let mut result = 0;
while !queue.borrow().is_empty() {
    let cur = match queue.borrow_mut().pop_front() {
        None => break,
        Some(cur) => cur,
    };
    if visited.borrow().contains(cur) {
        continue;
    };
    result += 1;
    visit(cur);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=3338277143cb6569d266d62fa300d084)

Although using `RefCell` feels like a bit of a cheat because it pushes the borrow checks from compile to run time, it is perfect for cases where we know what we're doing is fine, but we're unable to prove it to the current borrow checker. Additionally, `RefCell` is not expensive, it doesn't incur an allocation for example, and `borrow()` and `borrow_mut()` boil down to a check/update of a flag. It's best to measure its effect for your particular use case, but since all the checks are confined to a single block of code, I would expect the compiler to be able to elide them entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is a very clever workaround with the RefCell. But I still don't understand why the compiler has a problem with the function as shown here https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&edition=2018&gist=71fcb655bc8c4c95d3231074ff93e82f

Comment: @GregDan *But I still don't understand why the compiler has a problem with the function as shown here* - The first paragraph of the answer was supposed to address that. The problem is that the `visit` closure creates a mutable _capture_ of `queue` - you can think of the closure as an opaque struct to whose constructor you've passed `&mut queue`. Rust's borrow rules require there to be at most one mutable reference to a value, so as long as one `&mut queue` lives, you cannot do either `&queue` or `&mut queue`.

Comment: @GregDan On the other hand, `queue.is_empty()` is equivalent to `VecDeque::is_empty(&queue)`, so it needs to create a reference. Likewise, `queue.push_back(n)` is shorthand for `VecDeque::push_back(&mut queue, n)`, so it needs to create a mut reference. Neither of those is allowed by the borrow checker because the closure already possesses a `&mut queue`. My answer avoids that by using a `RefCell` which doles out `&mut queue` on a case-by-case basis, and only after a run-time check that the previous one was disposed of.

Comment: It turned out that adding `'a` lifetime param to all function params blocks the queue and the hashmap to be modified later in the code. Please see the solution in the comment to the other answer.

Comment: @GregDan I'm glad that you made it work - that's the approach from the second paragraph of this answer. (I don't know why it didn't compile for me, as I remember trying something very similar to that.) Its drawback is that your closure is no longer capturing anything, it might as well be a function. That is sometimes perfectly fine, but not always - sometimes you want your closure to capture because its number of arguments is fixed externally (e.g. because you're passing it as callback to some code that expects to call it with just `name` and knows nothing of `queue` etc.).